# Node Modules not installing properly Jest Enzyme not being detected and installed properly

Tags: npm, jestjs, node-modules, enzyme

I was wondering if anyone has come across an issue where they do an npm install  and the package appears in package.json but not in node_modules. Example:

I type 
`npm install --save-dev jest enzyme enzyme-adapter-react-16`
These packages appear in package.json but when I type jest on the command line I get the error message: **Cannot find module 'enzyme' from 'enzyme.config.js'**

With enzyme.config.js being:

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

I looked in package.json and the packages are there but the packages are not in the node_modules folder. Any idea why this could happen? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved. The TL;DR; of this is: In production mode npm doesn't install dev dependencies. I changed NODE_ENV variable to production then to 'remove' it I just commented it out and re sourced bash profile. This doesn't remove production mode. I had to go and set it explicitly again to undo production.